# Unable to resolve Android JUnit test runner

Tags: android, junit, android-instrumentation

I am trying to add an instrumentation test to our project, but it seems that Gradle doesn't properly add the Android JUnit Test Runner to the project's classpath. The test depenencies of my gradle build file looks like this:

```
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
```

We are using the latest version of the support library (24.0.0), but the current version of the test runner (JUnit runner) and Espresso use version 23.1.0. To resolve the version conflict, I force the runner (and Espresso) to use the newer version (I understand the implications, but we can't use the older version):

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-v13:24.0.0'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.0.0'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.0.0'
```

and:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.0.0'
    }
}
```

However, for some reason, Gradle doesn't add the `runner` package (under android.support.test). So

```
import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4;
```

throws an error: `cannot resolve symbol 'runner'`. Have cleared Android Studio's cache, restarted the IDE, cleared Gradle's cache (both project and global), all with no luck. Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Is it because the support-annotations has introduced backward incompatible changes (e.g. removing some APIs), and the test runner is broken (can't work with the newer version of the lib) because it's using the older (probably removed) APIs?

Comment: It seems that the issue has nothing to do with the version. I still get the same error even if I use the older version (used by the test runner). Any idea why?

Comment: Have same problem after updating Android Studio from 2.2.6 to 2.2.7

Comment: Downgraded Android Studio to 2.2.6 and reimported project (synchronize might not help) and JUnit resolved again. Seems that bug in AS 2.2.7.

Answer (score 2):

try adding:
`androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'`

Answer (score 1):

This is my old question but thought it might help to explain the issue and the solution. The issue was with the name of the debug build variant: if you name your debug build variant anything but `debug`, make sure to notify Android's Gradle plugin by adding `testBuildType "yourDebugBuildVariantName"` to your `build.gradle` script (your app module's `build.gradle` not the project global) in the `android{}` section, or rename your debug build variant to just `debug`. If you have multiple debug build variants, you need to specify one of them on which you'd like to run your tests, like: `testBuildType armDebug`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
...

android {

  testBuildType "myDebug" <-

  compileOptions { ... }

  sourceSets { ... }

  signingConfigs { ... }
}
```

Even with this explicit config, Gradle occasionally seems to have issues with running instrumentation tests. The best way to workaround this is to rename your debug build variant (the one you run your tests on) to `debug` if this is a feasible option for you.